# Two shortcuts for one action

Tags: qt, pyqt

I need two shortcuts for one action.

```
Ctrl+1 or ctrl+s
```

Is there any way how to do that?
Or I have to create copy of the action and than assign second shortcut to this action?

Comment: Did you look at `QAction::setShortcuts(const QList<QKeySequence> & shortcuts)`?

Comment: Write this as an answer please.. 
I am using qt designer and there is used just method setShortcut.
So I have to write a wrapper for this.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In order of install multiple shortcuts on an action you can use `QAction::setShortcuts(const QList<QKeySequence> & shortcuts)` function. For example:

```
QList<QKeySequence> shortcuts;
shortcuts << QKeySequence("Ctrl+1") << QKeySequence("Ctrl+S");
action->setShortcuts(shortcuts);
```

Comment: One line code : action->setShortcuts( QList<QKeySequence>() << tr("Ctrl+1") << tr("Ctrl+S") );

Comment: Or even better one-liner `action->setShortcuts({ tr("Ctrl+1"), tr("Ctrl+S") });`

Comment: Is there a way to do it within Qt Designer or editingg the ui file?

Comment: @MartinDelille, yes. Select a menu action on Designer, in the property editor find "shortcut" property and set the key sequence(s).

Comment: @vahancho it works for a single shortcut but not for two.

Comment: @MartinDelille, what doesn't work: you cannot set multiple shortcuts or you can, but it's only one that works? I use Qt 5.14.x and it offers to press shortcut, I do and it inputs something like "Ctrl+F, Ctrl+K" in the value field for the 'shortcut' property.