# Two or more shortcuts for one push button

Tags: c++, qt

I need to have several shortcuts for one push button. For example `Ctrl+W` and `Enter` and `Return` (`Enter` and `Return` are different in Qt), any of them would cause a click on the button. How to do this? If the button was `QAction`, I would call `setShortcuts()` ( See [Two shortcuts for one action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23388754/two-shortcuts-for-one-action) which is NOT a duplicate. It is different, relates to `QAction` not `QPushButton`. ) but `QPushButton` has only `setShortcut()` (singular), which seems to not allow this. What solution or hack wold you suggest?

Comment: set shortcuts for QAction, conect action's trigerred signal to same slot you connect pushbutton's on_click signal.

Comment: A hack? OK, just redirect several shortcuts from their slots to whatever you need xD

Comment: The big question is really: why would you do such a thing?

Comment: @Clearer so that you can use the numpad enter or the central return button ...

Comment: I could create actions to call the same slot as the button calls but this does not animate the click on the button. I tried connecting the actions to `animateClick()` slot of the button but it does not visualize the click either.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Two shortcuts for one action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23388754/two-shortcuts-for-one-action)

Comment: @UKMonkey - thank you - `Return` and `Enter`- this was exactly the main reason why I came up with this question. This is a bit annoying here, whenever I ask a question, there is always someone asking "Why do you need this?" Well, I need it, otherwise I would not ask. :)

Comment: @Clearer I have already linked this in my original question. And I explained why this does not work in my case.

Comment: @V.K. don't forget though half the questions here are XY problems - they're asking to help you better;  in addition if it's a good reason, then they learn something ... win win! :)

Comment: XY problems are usually more complicated stuff. I believe this one is very simple. As the last resort I will override the `QPushButton`, intercept `keyPressEvent` and emit some click event to the button to visualize it. But I believe this overkill for such a simple thing. I hope there is simpler solution. :)

Comment: @V.K. you could always catch the ctrl+w and then mark the button as selected - then either enter button, or space will trigger it

Comment: @V.K., when people ask about hacks and extraordinary methods, mostly their question is XY problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I have got a solution which is not that hacky. I can create a `QPushButton` and a `QAction`, then set multiple shortcuts for `QAction` using `QAction::setShortcuts()` and connect this action to `QPushButton::animateClick()`. At first this solution did not work because I called `connect(action, &QAction::triggered, button, &QPushButton::animateClick);`. The problem was with invisible default arguments. `QAction::triggered` sends `true`/`false` indicating whether the action is checked. But `QPushButton::animatedClick` expects number of milliseconds to remain visually 'pressed'. Therefore it remained 'pressed' only for 0 or 1 millisecond, which is not enough to notice it (the default value of the argument is 100 milliseconds). This can be solved using lambda, hence:

```
// 'this' refers to a parent widget
auto action = new QAction(this);
action->setShortcuts({ tr("Ctrl+W"), tr("Return"), tr("Enter") });
this->addAction(action);
auto button = new QPushButton(tr("Hey, click me!"));
connect(action, &QAction::triggered, [button](){ button->animateClick(); });
```

And that's it.