# Two Shortcuts for One Button in PyQt

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

In PyQt, how would you tie in two shortcuts for one button? I have scoured the QT documentation and StackOverflow, but the only thing I found was [Two shortcuts for one action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23388754/two-shortcuts-for-one-action), but that was for QT and I could not wrap my head around that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The only difference is that instead of using `QList` you should use the `list`:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        menubar = self.menuBar()
        menu = menubar.addMenu("File")
        foo_action = menu.addAction("foo")
        foo_action.setShortcuts(["Ctrl+1", "Ctrl+S"])
        foo_action.triggered.connect(self.on_triggered)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_triggered(self):
        print("on_triggered")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

In the case of QWidgets they do not have the `setShortcuts()` method, so one option is to use `QShortcut`s:

```
for sequence in ("Enter", "Return",):
    shorcut = QtWidgets.QShortcut(sequence, self.pushButton_eq)
    shorcut.activated.connect(self.pushButton_eq.animateClick)
```

Comment: I did this, `self.pushButton_eq.setShortcut(_translate("MainWindow", ["Return", "Enter"]))`, but I got `TypeError: translate(str, str, disambiguation: str = None, n: int = -1): argument 2 has unexpected type 'list'`

Comment: My programs full code is available [here](https://github.com/DSSecret-Studios-Dev/Virtual-Desktop). It's at `./Calculator/MainWindow.py`.

Comment: @DS_SecretStudios Why do you use `_translate`?

Comment: @DS_SecretStudios On the other hand in your question you point to an action (QAction) not a QPushButton.

Comment: That one button runs a function in my program, thus I though I could hook it up to the button.

Comment: @DS_SecretStudios change `self.pushButton_eq.setShortcut(_translate("MainWindow", "Return"))
        self.pushButton_eq.setShortcut(_translate("MainWindow", "Enter"))` to `for sequence in ("Enter", "Return",):
            QtWidgets.QShortcut(sequence, self.pushButton_eq, activated=self.pushButton_eq.animateClick)`

Comment: @DS_SecretStudios I have updated my answer indicating the solution for your case, also do not use translate. On the other hand if my answer helps you do not forget to mark it as correct, if you do not know how to do it then review the [tour], that is the best way to thank.

Comment: `foo_action.setShortcuts(["Ctrl+1", "Ctrl+S"])` works but only shows the first shortcut. When I swap them always the first is shown!!?? Why is that??

Comment: @KhalilAlHooti by design, the Qt developers did not see it necessary to show all the shorcuts, only the first.

Comment: Ahhaaa, interesting, thanks telling me. I spent hours trying to fix it. @eyllanesc is there a way to show all shortcuts??